# how to calibrate 3d lidar coordinate and 2d image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, calibration

I want to project a 3D position in LiDAR coordinate system into an image using LiDAR-Camera Calibration file. But there was an error when I projected it.

calibration.txt :

```py
Number: 1
LidarImageOffset
0
Angle : LR, UD, Rot (Radian)
3.113457,0.012906,-0.004688
TranslationMatrix (m)
0.020078,-0.056181,-0.089000
intrinsicCameraParameter(fx,fy,cx,cy,k1,k2,p1,p2)
1079.825866,1043.839566,960.015697,622.222143,-0.118815,0.060512,0.000484,-0.000989
```

This is the code I implemented.

```py
translation_vector = T
lr, ud, rol = R
#Translation point
points = np.array([x-T[0], y-T[1], z-T[2]],dtype=np.float32)

def rot_x(x):
  mat = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [0, np.cos(x), -np.sin(x)],
                  [0, np.sin(x), np.cos(x)]],dtype=np.float32)
  return mat
def rot_y(x):
  mat = np.array([[np.cos(x), 0, np.sin(x)],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [-np.sin(x), 0, np.cos(x)]],dtype=np.float32)
  return mat
def rot_z(x):
  mat = np.array([[np.cos(x), -np.sin(x), 0],
                [np.sin(x), np.cos(x), 0],
                [0, 0, 1]],dtype=np.float32)
  return mat

rot_mat_x =rot_x(rol)
rot_mat_y = rot_y(ud)
rot_mat_z = rot_z(lr)

rot_mat = np.array([[0,1,0],[0,0,-1],[-1,0,0]])
lidar2cam = np.eye(4,4,dtype=np.float32)
rot_matrix = rot_mat@rot_mat_x@rot_mat_y@rot_mat_z
result = np.dot(rot_mat, np.dot(rot_mat_x, np.dot(rot_mat_z,
 np.dot(rot_mat_y,points))))

points = np.array([result[0],result[1],result[2]])
points = points[:2] / points[2]
points = Intrins@np.array([points[0],points[1],1])
```

### error

[image]

I wonder if the implementation is wrong or where it is wrong

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please take this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Please provide your own efforts into solving the problem in terms of code, a.k.a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).